# Docker error - "hcsshim::ExpandScratchSize failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

I have been trying to start a docker-compose file of 2 Windows containers in a Windows 11 environment when I got the following error:

"hcsshim::ExpandScratchSize failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)"

I have tried to resolve this by:

- adding `storage-opts` in my Docker Daemon configuration
- doing system and image prune
- re-installing Docker Desktop

This has only started to happen on the latest version of Docker Desktop for Windows (I was able to run these containers until I updated to version 4.22.1).

Is anyone able to provide any assistance please?

EDIT 1: This also happens when I attempt to build a .NET Framework container (`docker build`, `docker run` and `docker compose` all seem to be affected by this error)

EDIT 2: This error no longer occurs when I installed an older version of Docker Desktop (4.21.1). As a workaround, this seems to be fine but I'm concerned as to how to resolve the error should it happen in the future

Comment: Try deleting and re-pulling the base image(s). Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue after messing with some settings on Docker Desktop. To resolve this, I went to troubleshoot by right-clicking on the Docker Desktop icon in the "show more icons" and selecting trouble shoot. Then I just reset it to factory settings and now it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Delete (rename) the `c:\ProgramData\Docker folder...` it's most likely corrupted.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please follow the [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for answering a question. Thanks for your contribution.